# A data structure with certain properties

Tags: c++11, data-structures, binary-tree, big-o, time-complexity

I want to implement a data structure myself in C++11. What I'm planning to do is having a data structure with the following properties:

- search.                O(log(n))
- insert.               O(log(n))
- delete.              O(log(n))
- iterate.             O(n)

What I have been thinking about after research was implementing a balanced binary search tree. Are there other structures that would fulfill my needs? I am completely new to this topic and thought a question here would give me a good jumpstart.

Comment: just curious: how did you came up with those requirements?

Comment: These requirements match `std::map` and `std::set`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will do further research on that. It is just part of a task I need to accomplish :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, using the existing standard library data types is definitely the way to go for production code. But since you are asking how to implement such data structures yourself, I assume this is mainly an educational exercise for you.

Binary search trees of some form (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree#Implementations) or B-trees (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) and hash tables (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) are definitely the data structures that are usually used to accomplish efficient insertion and lookup. If you want to go wild you can combine the two by using a tree instead of a linked list to handle hash collisions (although this has a good potential to actually make your implementation *slower* if you don't make massive mistakes in sizing your hash table or in choosing an adequate hash function).

Since I'm assuming you want to learn something, you might want to have a look at minimal perfect hashing in the context of hash tables (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function) although this only has uses in special applications (I had the opportunity to use a perfect minimal hash function exactly once). But it sure is fascinating. As you can see from the link above, the botany of search trees is virtually limitless in scope so you can also go wild on that front.

Comment: Wow - this as an amazing answer! You were right that this was in some sort educational - and you just nailed it by giving me those fascinating topics to read about! Thank you so much!